# How to limit requests to certain domain in nginx?

Tags: nginx, 403-forbidden, access-control

I have a domain like `sub.example.com`. I'd like to allow GET access to certain paths `uploads` only through `example.com`

Something like this:

```
  location ~ ^/uploads {
         allow example.com;
         deny  all;
        root /www/uploads;
        }
```

But nginx gives error for domain after `allow`. It only accepts IP address and I don't want to hardcode IP. There should be a better way?

How can I achieve this in nginx configs?

Answer (score 2):

```
server{
listen 80;
listen 443;

#put your certs here if you have, if not, just listen to port 80.

server_name example.com; #only requests coming from this host will enter this server bracket 


 location ~ ^/uploads {
     root /www/uploads;
  }
}
```

Set a server block to listen to a certain domain, and accept /uploads and deny them in the other server blocks(same location block but returning a 401 or 403).

If you want to treat different domains differently, it's good in nginx to separate the server blocks.

Comment: Well I already have `server_name sub.example.com;` configured on this server.

Comment: So set another one for example.com. In the sub.example.com you return 403; in uploads, and in example.com block you root /www/uploads. Everything else the same. Like this both domain and subdomain will do the same, except when they ask for /uploads (one will return error, the other will return upload).

If you edit your post with an aproximate configuration of your sub.domain.com server block, I can aproximate my answer as much as I can on what you want.